SQL Raiseerror to end successfully?
Is there a way to have RAISEERROR in SQL Server procedure, to raise the error, but still have the procedure 'finish' successfully?
Right now we have a  procedure where it ends with a RAISERROR and it prints out a total number of something - this is tied in with our logging system, so whenever a raise error happens, it also saves it to a log file.
We then use this log file in Hangfire to monitor any issues.
But problem is, that the procedure keeps showing up as Failed because of the RAISEERROR function.
Code snippet:
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @UnprocessedCollaterals)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);
        
        DECLARE @Count int;
        SELECT @Count = COUNT(DISTINCT CollUpdProcessPK)
        FROM @Unprocessed;

            RAISERROR ('Total: %d', 16, 1, @Count);

    END;

I tried doing it this way:
        BEGIN TRY
            RAISERROR ('Total: %d', 16, 1, @Count);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

        END CATCH

But that just ends with the RAISEERROR not executing I believe, since it doesnt show up in our logs.
Is there a different way of doing this perhaps?
Main goal:
Have RAISEERROR execute, but have the SQL Procedure to be 'successful'.

You should be able to lower the importance of raiserror such that it's not logged

Well, honestly, you are abusing RAISEERROR here as a fake log entry.  That's not what it's supposed to be used for.  Why not just insert the log entry into a new "log" table?

This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want this in the first place? Have RAISEERROR execute, but have the SQL Procedure to be 'successful'. isn't the actual goal, it's how you assume you can implement it. this is tied in with our logging system that's not what RAISEERROR is for. If you want to log in SQL, use SQL INSERT statements. I suspect you tried to use PRINT and found out they aren't returned immediately. Then you tried to use RAISEERROR as an immediate PRINT and run into other problems.

Using raiserror is a common way to get a progress report on a long running operation.

Unfortunately this is just how the existing system is built at the company, and we cant re-write it at this stage.
And the actual logging is in a .txt file, which is why theyve used RAISEERROR - would be good to have a seperate table for this, but not right now :D

As they aren't using NOWAIT with RAISERROR the only value it is providing is the string interpolation not flushing the buffer to see the messages immediately. Severity of 16 means this is regarded as an error though not an info message

You either want logging or progress reporting, which isn't the same thing. Logging doesn't have to be immediate. For client-side progress reporting you could use RAISERROR with a severity of 10 or less as a very crude reporting mechanism that can only send a string that has to be parsed by the client.

@TimRoberts RAISERROR can be used to report non-error information to the TDS client, provided the severity number is below the threshold: "@@ERROR is set to 0 by default for messages with a severity from 1 through 10." but they're using 16 which is above the threshold.

@PanagiotisKanavos It's crude, yes - but in complex procedures I use it to provide extra metadata, e.g. to allow clients to know ahead-of-time which resultset is being returned.

So the answer to your question is simple. Just set the severity to 10 or less. But we have no idea about what your logging system does and if that only logs exception messages or not

@Dai so you're using a sproc as ETL or orchestration? 8 years ago I'd say "that's crazy" but, with all-wise MS abandoning SSIS, SSRS, SSAS (all the features that made SQL Server a bargain) and pushing Azure equivalents ... I'm using Python for ETL nowadays, especially for importing from Excel or MySQL. I log to a table in addition to files though

@PanagiotisKanavos No, no - nothing that bad - but still quite legitimate. I'd need more than a textbox to explain - if you care to join me...

While RAISERROR "progress" can be good when you're sitting on the screen watching it execute, i don't agree with using it as a more automatic logging system. Well, i guess you can ignore the "logging" errors on the backend based on something and then consider execution to be a success if return status is 0. This system sounds kinda brittle, because it's complicated to read out all errors due to how tds works. Why not just log into a table and then use it to monitor your things. A lot of SQL Server versions supports table inserts

Great suggestions from the comments.
Its clear we need to re-write this whole part of the code for better error logging, but that will have to wait when we have more resources to do that :)
The end solution is quite simple. Not sure why I didnt think of this initially.
Changing the severity of RaiseError to below 10 gives me the desired effect.
Thanks all!
